# vb.net converting an exponent number to a whole number

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, .net-2.0

How can I convert a number with exponent value (such as 4.775900000000000e+004 ) to return a whole number, such as 47,759 using .net2.0 framework?

FYI, this is a weight category, not currency.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I guess it is a string, you can do `int.Parse(s, NumberStyles.AllowExponent);`. There might be problems with fractional parts, so use `double.Parse`, `float.Parse` or `decimal.Parse` when appropiate.

Comment: This will never be fraction. It will always be a whole number.

Comment: Then there is no problem in your case. I just wanted to mention it if someone finds this answer.